# If $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$ is absolutely continuous, can we interchange the spatial integral and time derivative? (from MSE)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I originally posted this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806120/if-t-to-lvert-f-cdot-t-rvert-l2-x2-is-absolutely-continuous-can-we-i).  But it seems more nontrivial than expected, so I guess MO is a more appropriate place to ask.

I repeat the question for the sake of completeness:

Let $f(x,t) : S^1 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. $f(x,t) \in L^q_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^p_x(S^1)\bigr) \cap W^{1,q'}_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^{p'}_x(S^1)\bigr)$ so that
2. $\partial_t f(x,t) \in L^{q'}_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^{p'}_x(S^1)\bigr)$. Here the time derivative is weak one in the context of Bochner spaces.

where $1<p' <2< p <\infty$ satisfy $1/p+1/p'=1$, while  $q, q' \in (1,\infty)$ are just $1/q + 1/q' >1$.

However, suppose additionally that $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$ is in fact "absolutely continuous".

Then, is it true that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2= 2\int_{S^1} f(x,t) \partial_t f(x,t) dx
\end{equation}
for a.e. $t \in [0,\infty)$?

I tried to prove this myself using the notion of Gelfand triple somehow, but things do not work since $q,q'$ are not "a priori" conjugate exponents.

From [a comment by Lorenzo Pompili](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806120/if-t-to-lvert-f-cdot-t-rvert-l2-x2-is-absolutely-continuous-can-we-i#comment10223136_4806120), I get the desired result if $p' \geq 2$. But the case $p' < 2$ remains unsettled.

I dearly appreciate any help.

Comment: Your link to a question originally went to a comment.  I changed it to link to the question; but then, later, when you reference "the above link", it appeared to be specifically to the comment, and so I edited accordingly.  I hope that was all right.

Comment: @LSpice oh...thank you so much for your kindness.

Comment: How the weak Bochner derivative is defined? I mean, function $f$ values in $L^p$, but its weak derivative in $L^{p'}$. What kind of integration by parts formula is here?

Comment: @NikitaEvseev  Just the same notion of weak derivatives as in real-valued cases.

Comment: @Isaac Do you mean $$
\int_0^\infty \varphi'(t) f(t)dt=-\int_0^\infty \varphi(t) \partial_tf(t) dt\quad \forall \varphi\in C_c^\infty((0,\infty))?
$$ But then on the left-hand side we have an element from $L^p$ and an element from $L^{p'}$ on RHS.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev Thank you very much for pointing out lack of explanation. I rewrote my question so that your issue is fully addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I will not assume function $$\psi(t) := \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$$ be absolutely continuous.

We have $f\in W^{1,q'}_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^{p'}_x(S^1)\bigr)$, so $f$ has a representative $\tilde f:[0,\infty)\to L^{p'}_x(S^1)$ which is absolutely continuous
and
$$
\tilde f(t) - \tilde f(0) = \int_0^t\partial_t f(t) dt, \quad\text{ in } L^{p'}_x(S^1)
$$
for all $t\in [0,\infty)$. By the Fubini theorem, we obtain that $\partial_t f(x,\cdot)$ is locally integrable (in $t$ ) for all $x$ outside null set $\Sigma\subset S^1$.

Define function $F:S^1 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.
$$
F(x,t) = \begin{cases} 
\tilde f(0) + \int_0^t\partial_t f(x,t) dt, \quad\text{ if  } x\in S^1\setminus\Sigma;\\
0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then for a.e. $x\in S^1$ function $F(x, \cdot)$ is absolutely continuous and $f(x,t) = F(x,t)$ a.e. $(x,t) \in S^1 \times [0,\infty)$.
Moreover
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t) = \partial_t f(x,t) \quad \text{ a.e. } (x,t) \in S^1 \times [0,\infty).
$$

Now return to function $\psi$.
We are going to show that $\psi$ has a weak derivative. For $\varphi\in C_0^\infty([0,\infty))$, and applying Fubini's theorem several times we have.
\begin{multline*}
\int_0^{\infty}\varphi'(t) \psi(t) dt 
= \int_0^{\infty}\varphi'(t) \int_{S^1}f(x,t)^2 dx dt \\
= \int_0^{\infty} \int_{S^1} \varphi'(t)f(x,t)^2 dxdt
= \int_0^{\infty} \int_{S^1} \varphi'(t)F(x,t)^2 dxdt\\
= \int_{S^1} \int_0^{\infty}  \varphi'(t)F(x,t)^2 dt dx
= \int_{S^1} -\int_0^{\infty}  \varphi(t) 2F(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t) dt dx\\
= -\int_0^{\infty}\varphi(t) 2\int_{S^1} f(x,t)\partial_t f(x,t) dx dt.  
\end{multline*}
So we conclude
$$
\partial_t \psi(t) = 2\int_{S^1} f(x,t)\partial_t f(x,t) dx.
$$

Then, it is easy to see that $\psi, \partial_t \psi \in L^{1}([0,\infty))$ and so $\psi \in W^{1,q}([0,\infty))$.
In particular, it means that $\psi$ has an absolutely continuous representative $\tilde \psi$ such that it is differentiable a.e. and
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\tilde\psi(t) = \partial_t \psi(t) = 2\int_{S^1} f(x,t)\partial_t f(x,t) dx
$$
for a.e. $t\in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: One thing : how do you conclude that $\partial_t \psi \in L^1$? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: That is, how do you know that $\int_{S^1} f(x,t) \partial_t f(x,t) dx$ is integrable in $t$?

Comment: @Isaac \begin{multline}
\int_0^{\infty} |2\int_{S^1} f(x,t)\partial_t f(x,t) dx| dt
\leq \int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_{S^1} |f(x,t)|^p \right)^{\frac1p}\left(\int_{S^1} |\partial_t f(x,t)|^{p'} \right)^{\frac{1}{p'}} dt\\
\left(\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_{S^1} |f(x,t)|^p \right)^{\frac{q}{p}} \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\left(\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_{S^1} |\partial_t f(x,t)|^{p'} \right)^{\frac{q'}{p'}} \right)^{\frac{1}{q'}}\\
= \|f \|_{L^q_t\bigl(L^p_x\bigr)}\cdot \|\partial_t f \|_{L^{q'}_t\bigl(L^{p'}_x\bigr)}
\end{multline}

Comment: No, $q$ and $q'$ are not conjugate exponents.

Comment: @Isaac Then, actually, we can conclude that $\partial_t \psi$ is locally integralbel. And this is enough for the desired equality.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. $q$ and $q'$ are NOT conjugate exponents and therefoer we cannot apply Holder inequality..

Comment: If we assume function $\psi$ to be absolutely continuous it means that it has locally integrable derivative.

Comment: True. But it does NOT necessarily mean that we can interchange the time derivative and spatial integral.

Comment: Ok. But what about the following: from previous we know that $\int_{S^1} \int_0^{\infty}  \varphi'(t)F(x,t)^2 dt dx
= \int_{S^1} -\int_0^{\infty}  \varphi(t) 2F(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t) dt dx$ is finite. Then by the Fubini theorem $\int_{S^1} F(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t) dx$ is integrable on support $\varphi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149855/discussion-between-nikita-evseev-and-isaac).

Comment: I am not sure I understand all the proof, but I think that right after you integrate by parts, you cannot use Fubini's theorem, since $\partial_tF\cdot F$ is not locally integrable in $[0,\infty)\times S^1$ (note that $q$ and $q'$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$). You might be able to use *Tonelli*'s theorem if $\varphi$ is sign definite, and then recover the general case by writing $\varphi$ as the sum of a non-negative and a non-positive test, smooth functions. That way maybe it all works